# How can I use the File Writer object in steroids js to write to the local JSON file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building an application with Steroids JS and I'd like to be able to overwrite the contents of the local JSON file my app gets data from upon my app's launch. I think the File Writer object is what I need to accomplish this task however I'm not quite certain of this an I'm not quite certain of how I can specifically write to my local JSON file under www/MyApp.JSON with it.

Information on File Writer : http://docs.appgyver.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter

Details

The FileWriter object offers a way to write UTF-8 encoded files to the device file system. Applications respond to writestart, progress, write, writeend, error, and abort events.

Each FileWriter corresponds to a single file, to which data can be written many times. The FileWriter maintains the file's position and length attributes, which allow the app to seek and write anywhere in the file. By default, the FileWriter writes to the beginning of the file, overwriting existing data. Set the optional append boolean to true in the FileWriter's constructor to write to the end of the file.

Text data is supported by all platforms listed below. Text is encoded as UTF-8 before being written to the filesystem. Some platforms also support binary data, which can be passed in as either an ArrayBuffer or a Blob.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>FileReader Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for Cordova to load
//
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
}

function gotFile(file){
    readDataUrl(file);
    readAsText(file);
}

function readDataUrl(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("Read as data URL");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function readAsText(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("Read as text");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}

function fail(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Example</h1>
<p>Read File</p>
</body>
</html>
```